BigQuery Extract Info from JSON Strings stored as String Data Type
My BQ tables are populated by a BQ module (load_table_from_dataframe) into a table and has below values as STRING type (including ```)
```json{   
"number": 123,   
"date": "2020-11-01",   
"last_date": "2020-12-30"
 }```


I am trying to extract the keys using multiple ways but I got NULL so I had to forcefully replace ``` into blank and extract the info. I thought this forum could help me with a better way than mine.
Below code works but I don't think this is the correct way to extract from JSON
SELECT

REPLACE(json_extract(json_extract((replace(REPLACE(FIELD_NAME,"```json",""),"```","")),"$"),"$[number]"),"\"","") as number

FROM
Table


Have you tried with JSON_VALUE?

Something doesn't feel right about the content of your column.  I would examine closely how the values in the columns are set.  Specifically, where are the "```json" characters coming from.  Let's focus on what you mean by a BQ Module and "load_table_from_dataframe".  You may be solving the wrong puzzle ... ask yourself how the data in the columns can NOT have those non-JSON prefixes and suffixes.

You can use the following query:
with table AS (
select json_object(
    'number', 123,
    'date', '2020-11-01',
    'last_date','2020-12-30',
    'array', ['0','1','2']
) as json
)
select 
 json_value(json, '$.number') as number -- To get the number
 , json_value(json, '$.date') as date_ -- To get the date
 , json_value_array(json, '$.array') as array_ -- To get the array
 , json_value(json, '$.object.foo') as foo -- To get the value of foo
 , json_value(json, '$.object.bar') as bar -- To get the value of bar
from table

Basically, in order to export values, you can use the JSON_VALUE() and for the arrays, you can use JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(). If you have any advanced cases, just read on the examples and play around a bit.
